# Commands won't write to file when script is executed by cron

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, cron

I used `crontab -e` to schedule the execution of a shell script that does ssh calls to a list of servers and gets information and prints to file. The output of `crontab -l` is:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
*   1   *   *   1,2,3,4,5   /bin/bash /Users/cjones/Documents/Development/Scripts/DailyStatus.sh
```

The script I am running logs to files the output of `echo "Beginning remote connections..." >> $logfile` however does not log to a file the output of the following loop:

```
for servers in $(cat hostnames.txt); do
    echo "Starting connection to $servers" >> $logfile
    (rsync -av /Users/cjones/Documents/Development/Scripts/checkup.sh cjones@$servers:~/checkup.sh > /dev/null
    echo""
    ssh -t $servers "sudo ./checkup.sh") >> $logfile
    echo ""
done
```

Pastebin of the full script: http://pastebin.com/3vD7Bba0

Additional note this script pushes the latest version of a management script then ssh's into the remote server to execute and capture the ouput. This work 100% of the time when ran manually. Any assitance would be helpful thanks!

Comment: I update the crontab to the following:

 `SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * 1,2,3,4,5 /bin/bash /Users/cjones/Documents/Development/Scripts/DailyStatus.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do `SHELL=/bin/sh` and the same with `PATH`. The spaces around `=` are wrong.

Also, use full paths when calling files in your script when you call it with crontab:

From

```
for servers in $(cat hostnames.txt); do
    echo "Starting connection to $servers" >> $logfile
    (rsync -av /Users/cjones/Documents/Development/Scripts/checkup.sh cjones@$servers:~/checkup.sh > /dev/null
    echo""
    ssh -t $servers "sudo ./checkup.sh") >> $logfile
    echo ""
done
```

to

```
while read $servers
do
    echo "Starting connection to $servers" >> $logfile
    (rsync -av /Users/cjones/Documents/Development/Scripts/checkup.sh cjones@$servers:~/checkup.sh > /dev/null
    echo""
    ssh -t $servers "sudo ./checkup.sh") >> $logfile
    echo ""
done < /path/to/hostnames.txt
       ^^^^^^^^^
```

Note the usage of `while read; do ... done < file` instead of the unnecessary `for host in $(cat ...)`.

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to add another -t to the ssh command to force a pseudo-terminal.

http://serverfault.com/questions/224307/ssh-fails-to-execute-remote-command-when-run-from-cron-bash-script-works-from

Comment: Oh, then it was a different problem than what I pointed out :) Glad to read your script is working